# Flutter can't build apk

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, build

I am trying to get apk, but it failed. The cause is about androidX incompatibility and I tried to solve it I did every thing an finally I received this error. Please help what should I do?

```
[  +32 ms] Building plugin cloud_firestore...
[  +19 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
[  +62 ms] LocalFile: 'C:\\src\\flutter\\.pub-cache\\hosted\\pub.dartlang.org\\cloud_firestore-2.0.0\\android\build.gradle' provides AGP
version: 3.5.4
[  +22 ms] "flutter apk" took 71,549ms.
[  +12 ms] The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
[  +59 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildPluginsAsAar (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:802:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:312:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:492:15)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:231:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:105:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: which version of your cloud_firestore plugin ?

Comment: I use 2.0.0 version @MilanPansuriya

Answer (score 0):

Try to below commands hope its helpful to you:

Clean your whole project :

```
flutter clean
```

Get all packages

```
flutter pub get
```

and then create your apk command

```
flutter build apk --release
```

if you used Android Studio Go to `TopBar -> Build -> Flutter -> Build APK`

Comment: it show error of incompatibility of android X

Comment: try to update current  version using `flutter upgrade` command because  I think  you use old version

Comment: I upgrade that now it is 2.5.1 stable but face with this error throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)